# JSF filterMatchMode="exact" is not getting displayed in the <p:column> inside the <p:dataTable>

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, datatable

I am trying to add a `filterMatchMode` attribute to a p:column but its not getting displayed
Here is my XHTML code

```
 <p:column  width="200" style="width:200px"
                                    id="costgroup"  
                                    headerText="costgrouptitlefilter"   filterBy="costgrouptitle"
                                    filterOptions="#{Bean.costgrouptitlefilter}"
                                    filterMatchMode="exact">
                                    <h:outputText value="#{row.costgrouptitle}" />
                                </p:column>
```

This `costgrouptitlefilter` is an array of SelectItem which is declared in the backing bean

Backing Bean Code:
I am calling this code in both init() method and on search(), where I will call the same method in search during an action event in the XHTML

```
private SelectItem[] costgrouptitlefilter =createFilterOptions();
```

I am calling a method given below :

```
private SelectItem[] createFilterOptions() {
        SelectItem[] options = null;


        if (_ipdp_actualsexplorerlist != null
                && _ipdp_actualsexplorerlist.size() > 0) {
            System.out.println("_ipdp_actualsexplorerlist>>>"+_ipdp_actualsexplorerlist.size());
            options = new SelectItem[_ipdp_actualsexplorerlist.size() + 1];

            options[0] = new SelectItem("", "Select");
            for (int i = 0; i < _ipdp_actualsexplorerlist.size(); i++) {
                options[i + 1] = new SelectItem(_ipdp_actualsexplorerlist
                        .get(i).getCostgrouptitle(), _ipdp_actualsexplorerlist
                        .get(i).getCostgrouptitle());
            }
        }
        return options;
    }
```

I am adding all the values in a specific column and adding it to a

SelectItem[] options.

The `return options` have the correct size of the array.But the column is showing only the header in the XHTML and the selectmenu which I created above is not getting displayed.

What is the problem with my code above ?

Comment: Can you provide your entire facelet code? Instead of only the column. Where is the column located, BTW?